# Why does Spark not push down a filter to before a groupBy with collect_list?

Tags: apache-spark

Consider this example:

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


with pyspark.SparkContext(conf=pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]')) as sc:
    spark = pyspark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    df = spark.createDataFrame([
        [2020, 1, 1, 1.0],
        [2020, 1, 2, 2.0],
        [2020, 1, 3, 3.0],
    ], schema=['year', 'id', 't', 'value'])

    df = df.groupBy(['year', 'id']).agg(f.collect_list('value'))
    df = df.where(f.col('year') == 2020)
    df.explain()
```

which yields the following plan

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Filter (isnotnull(year#0L) AND (year#0L = 2020))
+- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[year#0L, id#1L], functions=[collect_list(value#3, 0, 0)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(year#0L, id#1L, 200), true, [id=#23]
      +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[year#0L, id#1L], functions=[partial_collect_list(value#3, 0, 0)])
         +- *(1) Project [year#0L, id#1L, value#3]
            +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[year#0L,id#1L,t#2L,value#3]
```

I would like Spark to push the filter `year = 2020` to before the `hashpartitioning`. If the aggregation function is `sum`, Spark does it, but it does not do it for `collect_list`.

Any ideas as to why this is not the case, and whether there is a way to address this?

The reason for doing this is that without a filter pushdown, the statement for 3 years (e.g. `year IN (2020, 2019, 2018)` performs a shuffle between them. Also, I need to express the filter after the groupBy in code.

More importantly, I am trying to understand why Spark does not push the filter down for some aggregations, but it does for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at the aggregate function that you are using.

### `collect_list`

From the doc below -

```scala
/**
   * Aggregate function: returns a list of objects with duplicates.
   *
   * @note The function is non-deterministic because the order of collected results depends
   * on the order of the rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.
   *
   * @group agg_funcs
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def collect_list(columnName: String): Column = collect_list(Column(columnName))
```

[collect_list](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L311) is a non-deterministic operation and its result depends on the order of rows.

Now look at the [Optimizer.scala#PushPredicateThroughNonJoin](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L1075),

```
// SPARK-13473: We can't push the predicate down when the underlying projection output non-
    // deterministic field(s).  Non-deterministic expressions are essentially stateful. This
    // implies that, for a given input row, the output are determined by the expression's initial
    // state and all the input rows processed before. In another word, the order of input rows
    // matters for non-deterministic expressions, while pushing down predicates changes the order.
    // This also applies to Aggregate.
```

**Since the above operation is non-deterministic i.e. the result is dependent on the order of rows of underlying dataframe, spark can't push the predicate because it changes the order of rows.**

Comment: Great answer. Do you know if there is any way to `collect_list` in a deterministic way? E.g. can I apply an orderBy somewhere to make it deterministic?

Comment: hard to follow, i would not have thought about this this way. order by comment above - try it out and tell us...@JorgeLeitao

Comment: even harder to follow, if you do not use order by, sort then i would think who cares then?

Comment: from @JorgeLeitao - **_Do you know if there is any way to collect_list in a deterministic way? E.g. can I apply an orderBy somewhere to make it deterministic?_**  -> I think, we can't make any spark Collect operations deterministic as they are hardcoded as **false** in the repo. check - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/collect.scala#L48

Comment: a misser in my view that makes little sense in reality, but nice to know